# Compartilhar com dados da licença automaticamente

Tags: suporte, licença

Tendo em vista que é "chato" preencher todos os [requisitos necessários](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) para compartilhar algo do SO, de acordo com a licença, existe alguma ferramente para automatizar esse processo? Digo, igual o "compartilhar" que possuem nas perguntas/respostas já com os dados obrigatórios para compartilhar.

Comment: Talvez seja legal algo como o link do [bibtex](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/4917/citation), mas gerando os dados adequados para atribuição. talvez `http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/4917/attribution`

Comment: Poderia ser um pedido de novo recurso, não?

Comment: @Bacco A ideia seria algo tipo isso mesmo. Vou elaborar uma proposta amanhã.

Comment: @Math Eu não sabia se existia ou não algo do tipo, por isso apenas perguntei primeiro. Mas a ideia e propor sim.

Comment: Blz. Tb não sei se existe, mas acredito que não.

Comment: Não acho uma ideia ruim, mas ao mesmo tempo não vejo como criar um "formato padrão" de compartilhamento que vá servir pra maioria dos casos. A ideia do bibtex é boa, mas também tem utilidade bem restrita. Acho que o retorno não justifica o trabalho...

Comment: @Gabe No caso eu queria apenas saber se existe ou não tal ferramente. Vou mostrar os pontos que eu acho que deveria ter algo parecido assim que tiver tempo. Mas isso veio da antiga licença, onde tinha 4 itens obrigatório, não sei se a MIT possui as mesmas necessidades.

Comment: @Randrade Ah, sim... Então não, não existe `:)`